# how to hide or change popup which comes before NFC Tag detection?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nfc, core-nfc

is it possible to detect **CoreNFC** tag without that default PopUp ?
and if not ? can i change icon in it or somehow modify that PopUp ?

i am using objective c.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @mag_zbc & michael, my question is slightly different because i needed to change/ modify the PopUp too.
Thanks

Comment: Any update on this? Is it still impossible today?

Comment: I think it is possible now, I have seen it working in the Hyatt app, and I have heard another developer use it for their company entry as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can’t avoid presenting the alert. It’s also not possible to edit the image on it, the only detail that is configurable is the `alertMessage` (Details [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/nfcreadersessionprotocol/2919987-alertmessage)) parameter on your instance of NFCReaderSession.